# Set C++ program as a game

Tags: discord

I made a game in C++.

Now I want to set it as a game. 
This means that I want discord to recognize it as a game ("Playing **MYGAME**").

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the requirements to get your game shown on Discord Store and detect it as a game: [How to get your game on Discord](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/game-and-server-management/how-to-get-your-game-on-discord). There you find the following notable things:

```
Throughout this process, we'll reference your "app".
An app, or application, is an entity on Discord that represents something you've built: a bot, an OAuth2 app, or in this case your game.

We need to make an app for your game:
Create a new app at https://discordapp.com/developers/applications
When doing so, make sure you select your team from the Team dropdown

You're now looking at a blank slate of creativity. Give your game a pretty icon and exciting description here.
Next, click on Server Commerce Checklist in the sidebar, and we'll get to the good stuff.
```